# Are there any region restrictions on the activation of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

Microsoft does not sell Windows 8 DVDs in China, We can only update to Windows 8 from Windows 7, Vista or Windows XP SP3.

However, I am an Ubuntu user, I don't have Windows 7, Vista or Windows XP SP3 installed in my laptop.

**If I buy a Windows 8 Pro DVD from Amazon (USA), can it be activated from China?**

Comment: I don't see why not. They don't even know where in the world you are. If they use your IP address, you could always use a proxy or vpn or do a telephone activation using a calling card.

Comment: I've edited the question to be a little less localised, but do note that China is a special case, as there is a [Windows for China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Regional_restrictions_and_variations) that is Chinese only, and cheaper than the international version. This may be the one you are referring to. As far as I know, the international version should be installable in China.

Comment: I don't see why not as well. Not being sold there is fine I guess, but say I bought a copy of Win8 before travelling to China. Will customs confiscate it? If not, why shouldn't I be allowed to activate something I paid for, just because I'm in China?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does do region checking because certain versions of windows have some features enabled or disabled. It is to do with EU regulations and definitely Chinese law!

I am not sure what will happen in China but they cannot stop it from getting activated. If you have problems activating it- Use a VoiP service and dial into USA Number to activate it. No problem. You can also proxy or SSH into a US server to protect your origin(but that is more advanced)